# How to save objects in list without unique ID (belongsTo, hasMany)

Tags: java, android, collections, has-many, belongs-to

When I have collection, where each object is unique but they belong to some parentId, how should I store it?

My Idea is

- `ArrayList <MyType> objects_list;` // to store those objects
- `ArrayList <int[]> parents_list` // to store `parent_id` vs `int[] object_list.id`'s

So connection would be

- `object_list.item belongsTo parents_list.item`
- `parents_list.item hasMany object_list.item`

Isn't there some more efficient, more Java, solution?

---

Little more explain:

I have collection of object, where every object has `parent_id` in some variable within.
I need to store those objects, so that I could easily select all objects by their `parent_id`

And I cannot use simple one ArrayList with `parent_id` as `key`, because `key` has to be unique.

So how to store them, to fetch all objects by their `parent_id` like `Collection.getByParentId(parent_id)` ?

Comment: Its not clear enough what you are trying to acheive could you be more specific....

Comment: @LalitPoptani added explanation

Comment: It would be a good idea to use a  Map here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584107/how-to-save-objects-in-list-without-unique-id-belongsto-hasmany/7584202#7584202) said before, store the parent ID in `MyType`.

```
// all MyType objects
List<MyType> objects;

// This way you could track the relations
// (you would have to update this on change)
Map<Integer, List<MyType>> relations;
```

Comment: Guava's MultiMap implements Map<Integer, List<MyType>>.

Comment: Good to now, I'll keep your suggestion in mind. Basically it should do exactly the same internally what I suggested...

Comment: Thanks, I'd better use my own implementation than some library in this case.

Comment: @Knickedi that's correct and it takes care of the nuisance of checking to see if a List already exists for a key and creating it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Guava's [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)

```
ListMultimap<Integer, MyType> map = ArrayListMultimap.<Integer, MyType>create();
```

Then you can do:

```
List<MyType> children = map.get(parentId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes; keep `parent_id` in MyType, where it belongs, or don't store it anywhere, and use the parent object's ID when you need it (it's unclear as worded what you're actually trying to accomplish).

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> myObjects = new HashMap(); // Assuming parent_id is Integer
```

You can access it like this:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myObjectsArray = myObjects.get(parent_id);
```

Comment: I had to be completely blind! It's so obvious when you wrote it down. Thanks!